# Wrong padding for background color on ul li:hover in CSS3?

Tags: html, css, sass, menubar

I try to make a horizontal menu bar with a table in HTML using CSS to design it. But the **padding** doesn't work the way I think it should: when I'm trying to change the background color of the whole li when the user "hovers it" with the mouse. But the padding seems to get wrong.

Here's my code in CSS (using Sassy CSS):

```
/* just to be sure the default of browser doesn't change look */
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

/* some other design code ... */

#nav-menu {
    padding:5px;
    text-align:center;
    
    /* change background: browser specific gradient */
    background:$menu-bgcolor;
    
    li {
        list-style:none;
        display:inline;
        padding:2px 10px 2px 10px;
        
        :hover {
            background-color:$deco-dark;
            color:$deco-verylight;
        }
    }           
}
```

But the result looks something like the following:

[image: A menu item on hover status -- you can see that padding doesn't cover all li area.]

As you can see the changed background color, which is `$deco-dark` in this case, doesn't affect the whole `li` area (the area with gradient), as i would expect. What can I do to change this behavior?

Comment: Are you using a table or UL? Your css indicates UL but your problem description says table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With SASS, the following:

```
li {
  :hover { } }
```

will apply styles to any `:hover` elements *inside* the `li`. What you need is

```
li {
  &:hover {} }
```

which will apply the style to the `li` element itself when it's hovered. Right now, the style is likely being applied only to the `a` inside the `li`.

Comment: Thanks, that pointed me to the right direction and solved the main point, that I didn't understand. I really didn't know that stuff with the '&' operator ... but now I figured it out! Tanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your li's to `display: inline-block;` instead.

Comment: I did, but still having the same problem.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like your padding isn't being applied because it's not a block element. Try display:block and float:left for li's.  And add overflow:auto; to #nav-menu.  If it is being applied, then just increase the top and bottom padding from 2px to whatever it needs.

Comment: Far too complicated. See above.

Answer (score 0):

You could also place anchors in the li, then style the anchors accordingly. This is what I usually do. Also, like Brant said, are you using a list or a table? A list is probably better and is what you have implemented so just use that.